# CSS Issue: I need to move text closer to banner

Tags: css, obs

Firstly I am not a developer but I need a quick fix with CSS in my OBS.

On the following picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/acqOw.jpg you can see "AKII0 is now following".

How could I move the text "AKII0 is now following" up, closer to the banner?

Thanks for help

**Html**

```html
<!-- alert image -->
<div id="alert-image-wrap">
  <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
</div>

<!-- main alert box window -->
<div id="alert-text-wrap">

  <!-- alert text -->
  <div id="alert-text">

    <!-- alert message -->
    <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
    <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->
    <div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
    <div id="alert-user-message">{userMessage}</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#alert-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#alert-box.hidden,
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
#alert-text {
  padding: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000, 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 3px #000,
    0px 0px 4px #000, 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
#alert-message,
#alert-user-message {
  text-align: center;
}
#alert-user-message img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 1em;
}
#alert-image {
  position: relative;
}
#alert-image video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#alert-message > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
#alert-image {
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
#alert-text {
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
#alert-text-wrap {
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The image you have posted is far too small. Please, ***EDIT*** your question and clarifty exactly what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried (unsuccessfully) so far to do this yourself. Thanks

Comment: Would be hard to tell without seeing how your HTML is structured

Comment: Its not a site, its just simple alert in OBS

Comment: HTML --> https://pastebin.com/vhVbYUQV

Comment: Full CSS --> https://pastebin.com/4zhy4sHG

Comment: you need to post your code HERE, not at another site (i.e.: edit your question!)

Comment: Where is `#wrap` and `#alert-box`?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to see whats going on with the small screenshot. You might want to try to recreate this in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/).

And to complicate things, many of your CSS IDs don't seem to apply to the HTML you shared. I also noticed you have `#alert-image` and `#alert-text` referenced twice in your CSS. All of these things can cause crossed-wires in your results if you're not careful.

But off the top of my head, I'd put your image and text into a container div. Then I'd arrange them in the container div as needed using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Because you're using padding, you can further adjust them using padding.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<!-- your new container -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- alert image -->
  <div id="alert-image-wrap">
    <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
  </div>

  <!-- main alert box window -->
  <div id="alert-text-wrap">

    <!-- alert text -->
    <div id="alert-text">

      <!-- alert message -->
      <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
      <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->
      <div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
      <div id="alert-user-message">{userMessage}</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

(I moved those IDs and their properties into the box below if I couldn't see that they applied to the HTML you provided).

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  display: flex; /* Flex ensures items can be arranged in columns or rows and they wrap */
  flex-direction: column; /* Arranging things so they stack */
  justify-content: center; /* Puts the image and text together */
}
#alert-image {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px; /* increase this if you want more padding */
}
#alert-image { /* redundant, merge into the original ID above */ 
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
#alert-text-wrap {
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
#alert-text {
  padding: 20px; /* This is equal to the 4 items below. Break it up as needed to get your spacing right.
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px; */
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000, 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 3px #000,
    0px 0px 4px #000, 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
#alert-text { /* redundant, merge into the original ID above */ 
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}
#alert-message,
#alert-user-message {
  text-align: center;
}
#alert-user-message img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 1em;
}
```

**Potentially useless CSS**

This CSS didn't seem to apply to the HTML you provided.

```
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#alert-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#alert-box.hidden,
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
#alert-image video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#alert-message > span > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I hope this helps you move in the right direction!